# Weak solution of a problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this simple question :

Let $u_0\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$

in the problem of the transport equation : $\partial_tu(x,t)+c\partial_xu(x,t)=0$ with the initial condition $u|_{t=0}=u_0$ (in $L^1(\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R)$)

How to prove that the weak solution is given by : $u(t,x)=u_0(x-ct)$ is in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R)$

Thank you very much !

Comment: The function $x \mapsto u(t,x)$ on some interval $[a,b]$ is the same as the function $u_0(x)$ on $[a-ct,b-ct]$, which is given to be locally integrable. So that gives you local integrability in $x$. I'm not sure what else you're trying to get.

Comment: i think that i have to prove that for all R>0, for all T>0 we have always $\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-T}^{T}|u(t,x)|dtdx<\infty$ am i right ?

Comment: I don't know, it comes down to your definitions. But still, that follows from the previous statement (why?)